# how to use spring data jpa Sort.Order.nullslast

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I used nullslast() as the sample code as below,

```
        List<Sort.Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

        Sort.Order orderAuditTime = new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC,"auditTime");
        Sort.Order orderEntryTime = new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC,"customer.entryTime");

        orders.add(orderAuditTime.nullsLast());
        orders.add(orderEntryTime);

        sort = new Sort(orders);
```

but got  sql without nulls last like :

```
order by
    auditrecor0_.audit_time desc,
    customer1_.entry_time desc limit ?
```

Can someone help me why orderAuditTime.nullsLast() doesn't work ?

The database is postgre and the orm framework is hibernate.

Comment: If audittime is null,it will in the top of the page.And orderAuditTime.nullsFirst() doesn't work as well.

Comment: sql server doesn’t    support nulls last or nulls first ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, instances of Sort.Order get converted to javax.persistence.criteria.Order. This interface does not have support for nulls first/last:

```
package javax.persistence.criteria;

public interface Order {
    Order reverse();
    boolean isAscending();
    Expression<?> getExpression();
}
```

Thus, nulls first/last specified on Sort.Order is ignored.